# Использование массива в функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В представленном ниже коде, в моём, вероятно не самом толковом понимании функция получает массив "arr" в аргумент "list", должна его отсортировать и вернуть отсортированный массив в переменную arrSorted. И при всём, при этом, изначальный, глобальный массив вроде как тоже должен оставаться без изменений, ведь все действия производимые с ним были внутри тела функции, но на деле, по итогу выполнения кода и arr, и arrSorted становятся отсортированными.

```js
var arr = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "CSS"];
var arrSorted = sortFunc(arr);

function sortFunc(list){
  return list.sort();
}

console.log( arrSorted ); // CSS, HTML, JavaScript
console.log( arr ); // CSS, HTML, JavaScript
```

Comment: list.sort() у Вас и сортирует исходный массив, а потом вы его возвращаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб было совсем понятно, что это не копия массива, добавил элемент

```js
var arr = [ "HTML", "JavaScript", "CSS" ];
// Здесь вы просто получили ссылку на arr
var arrSorted = sortFunc( arr );

function sortFunc ( list ) {
    return list.sort();
}

// +++ Добавлено
arrSorted.push( "PHP" );

console.log( arrSorted ); // [ 'CSS', 'HTML', 'JavaScript', 'PHP' ]
console.log( arr ); // [ 'CSS', 'HTML', 'JavaScript', 'PHP' ]
```

Comment: а тут почему просто sort вызывается, а не `Array.prototype.sort.call`?

Answer (score 1):

Как я написал в комментарии Вы и сортируете исходный массив, а затем возвращаете его из функции.

Чтобы этого избежать создавайте копию:

```
let newArr = arr.slice(0)
```

---

```
var arr = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "CSS"];
var arrSorted = sortFunc(arr.slice(0));

function sortFunc(list){
  return list.sort();
}

console.log( arrSorted ); // CSS, HTML, JavaScript
console.log( arr ); // CSS, HTML, JavaScript
```

Comment: Получается массивы и обычный примитивные переменные при ~ аналогичном сценарии работают по разному, верно? (Извиняюсь за криво предоставленный код, но не могу разобраться как его корректно отредактировать в комментарии)

`var a = 'a';`
`var b = test( a );`

`function test( a ){`
`return a.toUpperCase();
}`

`console.log( a ); // a`
`console.log( b ); // A`

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков верно, примитивы не передаются по ссылке